# write espresso tests for an apk file

Tags: android-studio, android-espresso, android-testing

I have got a apk file and I need to write espresso tests for some few scenarios.

I tried using apktool to extract source code. It generated .smali files. Can anyone guide me that how can I generate java source files and write espresso tests for this apk?

Else, is there any way I can write espresso tests and execute them on an emulator?